# How to Dump a UVM TB class diagram?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Is it possible to dump a UVM(or SV) TB class/object hierarchy diagram?

It can help with easy code browsing and looking at the TB in general.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questa has this capability as an add on. https://verificationacademy.com/verification-horizons/june-2014-volume-10-issue-2/Visualizer-Debug-Environment-Class-based-Testbench-Debugging-using-a-New-School-Debugger-Debug-This

Comment: u understand that it might not be available before the compile, can something like this be extracted from vcd/fsdb?

Comment: Mentor has product called HDL Designer that can extract that information from the source code. It has to be compiled by _some_ tool in order to get that information. VCD is for post-simulation data, not analysis of the source code.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it is possible to dump it into waveform dynamically (this may need simulator support). But if you just want to print the whole UVM verification environment that you created, then call `uvm_top.print_topology()` at the `end_of_elaboration_phase`.

```
class your_test extends uvm_test;
  //...
  virtual function void end_of_elaboration_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    uvm_top.print_topology();
  endfunction
endclass
```

Comment: I was looking for something like [this](http://www.studio-muzzi.com/project/docs/UVMdocs_smu/uvm-1.1d/classuvm__object__coll__graph.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to print the entire topology, create a uvm_table_printer in your base test, and then use it in your end_of_elaboration_phase to print your class heirarchy in table format

```
class my_test extends uvm_test

uvm_table_printer m_printer;
// .... All other class variables

virtual function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
  super.build_phase(phase);
  m_printer = new();
  // Rest of your build phase
endfunction

virtual function void end_of_elaboration_phase(uvm_phase phase);
   `uvm_info(get_full_name(), "Printing test topology", UVM_NONE)
    uvm_top.print_topology(m_printer);
endfunction

endclass;
```

This will print your entire class heirarchy in a readable table format. Note that it doesn't print out connections between ports though